# Error when "cordova emulate blackberry10"

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

It produces following output:

```
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "blackberry10"
    Preparing blackberry10 project
    Running on emulator for platform "blackberry10" via command "cmd" /c "project_root"\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\run --emulator
    [Error: An error occurred while emulating/deploying the blackberry10 project.
    fs.js:418
      binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
              ^
    TypeError: path must be a string
        at Object.fs.open (fs.js:418:11)
        at Object.fs.readFile (fs.js:206:6)
        at _self.findConnectedSimulator ("project_root"\PLATFO~1\BLACKB~1\cordova\lib\target-utils.js:182:12)
        at Object.async.series.ip ("project_root"\PLATFO~1\BLACKB~1\cordova\lib\run:111:21)
        at "project_root"\PLATFO~1\BLACKB~1\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:561:25
        at iterate ("project_root"\PLATFO~1\BLACKB~1\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:131:13)
        at Object.async.eachSeries ("project_root"\PLATFO~1\BLACKB~1\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:147:9)
        at Object.async.series ("project_root"\PLATFO~1\BLACKB~1\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:560:19)
        at getTargetName ("project_root"\PLATFO~1\BLACKB~1\cordova\lib\run:108:15)
        at fn ("project_root"\PLATFO~1\BLACKB~1\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:579:34)
    ]
```

`cordova build blackberry10` is working normally. Emulator is also working normally.

Comment: Same problem. I guess no one is doing it.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov I've posted solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [bryanhiggins proposed](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Error-when-cordova-emulate-blackberry10/m-p/2677863#M41639):

```
platforms\blackberry10\cordova\target add mysim <ip address> -t simulator --pin <simulator PIN>
cordova emulate blackberry10 --target=mysim
```

Looks like plain `cordova build blackberry10` isn't working because of bug in cordova. I'll update answer in case better solution will be found or it will be fixed.

Comment: in my case it looks like I *have to* pass the pin again when connecting to the emulator, for example: `cordova emulate blackberry10 --devicepass 123456`

Comment: @Aras so, pin or devicepass? I'm not sure but maybe you just have device password set up on your emulator?

Comment: I had to use `devicepass`, I think it is the password I entered when enabling development mode from inside the simulator. I dont understand *why* this is needed, but it my case that is the only way I managed to connect to the simulator. I think it is a different issue from what is described here though.